# if conditional each condition works on own but not together

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I tested each statement on its own and it works, but when I use || it ignores the !driver.getText().toString().equals("")part of the statement. Any ideas?

```
 if((!driver.getText().toString().equals(""))|| (canDrive>=0) )
```

Comment: You can make this a little cleaner by using `String.isEmpty()` instead of `equals("")`

Comment: The LHS will always be evaluated - are you sure this is the actual code?

Comment: What do you mean it "ignores the `!driver.getText().toString().equals("")`" part?

Comment: When run the condition is ignored

Comment: .isEmpty() is causing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` operator means *or* - so if either condition is true, the test succeeds. If you want to both conditions to be true, use `&&`.

More reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: Thanks, I feel like an idiot.

Comment: @Aaron - No problem. The link is to the Java Tutorials, a great resource in general for beginning Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform both parts of the condition use '|' operator. I.e.

```
if(driver.getText().toString().length() > 0 | canDrive >= 0)
```

Though, the left part of the statement should be executed always: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24

Comment: The OP is alleging that the first part is not being run, not the second.

Answer (score 0):

If compiler found canDrive >=0 than defiitely it will ignore rest of part of condition 
because you are using || (or) condition so this will happened,

other wise perfect,

i have tried see the code.

```
class test{
    public static void main(String[] arr){
    String str = TestString";
    int canDrive = 1;
    if(!str.toString().equals("") || canDrive >=0)
        System.out.println("pass");
        else
        System.out.println("fail");
    }
}
```